# BeautifulSoup scraping the specific href that has a class that it's repeat at least twice

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have to extract from different web data sheet like [this](http://sac.gencat.cat/sacgencat/AppJava/organisme_fitxa.jsp?codi=2612) the section with url of website.

The problem is that the class “vermell_nobullet” than has the href than I need its repeat at least twice.

How to extract the specific class “vermell_nobullet” with the href of website.

**My code**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import requests

def parse_url(url): 
    response = requests.get(url) 
    content = response.content  
    parsed_response = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml") # Variable que filtre pel contigut lxml
    return parsed_response 


depPres = "http://sac.gencat.cat/sacgencat/AppJava/organisme_fitxa.jsp?codi=6"

print(depPres)

soup = parse_url(depPres)

referClass = soup.find_all("a", {"class":"vermell_nobullet"})

referClass
```

**Output that I have:**

```
[<a class="vermell_nobullet" href="https://ovt.gencat.cat/gsitfc/AppJava/generic/conqxsGeneric.do?webFormId=691">
                            Bústia electrònica
                        </a>,
 <a class="vermell_nobullet" href="http://presidencia.gencat.cat">http://presidencia.gencat.cat</a>]
```

**Output that I want**:

```
http://presidencia.gencat.cat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put condition like if `text` and `href` is same from `a` tag you can take
particular tag

```
referClass = soup.find_all("a", {"class":"vermell_nobullet"})

for refer in referClass:
    if refer.text==refer['href']:
        print(refer['href'])
```

Another Way find last `div` element and also find last `href` using `find_all` method

```
soup.find_all("div",class_="blockAdresa")[-1].find_all("a")[-1]['href']
```

Output:

```
'http://presidencia.gencat.cat'
```